# Does my app contains "encryption" App Store regulations

Tags: ios, encryption, app-store, app-store-connect, publishing

I have an app that uses keychain to "save password function". When user logs into app password is encrypted by our custom made algorithm and then send to server by http/https(user defines server URL by himself, app is part of complex system provided by our firm, not standalone app for every user), then server decrypts pass and encrypt with another algorithm and checks for existence in database. Our app is not going to be published in US, Europe only for now.

Now we are about to publish app to App Store and I am wondering if it falls under regulations. I know that https is now exempt but how about when combined with keychain + custom encryption for login?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your "custom encryption"?

Comment: Its our private algorithm, based on randomising and bit shifts, not using any "documented" algorithm.

Comment: In other words, totally insecure?

Comment: for the sake of question, lets say yes, insecure.